# What's wrong with my format of passing data using $.getJSON?

Tags: jquery, getjson, cherrypy, ajaxform

Could I please borrow a second pair of eyes to see what's wrong with my Ajax request format here.

First I passed my parameters as an object, like this:

```
$.getJSON('selectOne', {'modelClass': 'Address', 'id': '3'}, function(json, textStatus) {
  $('span#address_line').append(json);
});
```

Instead of the value `'Address'` being sent to the back end, the key `'modelClass'` was actually what my server gets. Same case with `'id'` instead of `'3'`.

Then I changed the parameter part into an array, like this:

```
    $.getJSON('selectOne', ['Address', '3'], function(json, textStatus) {
      $('span#address_line').append(json);
    });
```

And now both parameters are sent as `undefined`.

It never works. What's wrong here?

My back-end server is a python framework called cherrypy.

EDIT: here I paste what the server complains for the first scenario:

```
    500 Internal Server Error

    The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
... ...
      File "/home/njh/gui_Base.py", line 30, in selectOne
        data_record = db.query(modelClass).filter(modelClass.id == id).one()
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: In your fist example you open an object `{` but close an array `]`. Is this a typo in your question or your real code?

Comment: The first one looks like a syntax error, as it's an object in one end, and an array in the other end? You should show us how you're catching this on the server.

Comment: @Turnip, thanks for noting, it was a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: @adeneo, thanks for the reminding. I paste the server response now.

Comment: What it's the server side code? `modelClass` is expected to be a SQL Alchemy model, not a string.

Comment: @cyraxjoe, that part I've already fixed by tacking a SQL Alchemy model onto it. The problem is still that it never gets the intended arguments.

Comment: I think that you question cannot be answered unless you put more information, like URL, method definition, what cherrypy handler are you using, cherrypy tools, etc.

Comment: @cyraxjoe, This is Not a back-end problem. The browser console clearly indicates that the data passed to the server is not what expected. When you pass an array and what you actually send is an array of undefined, it's the front-end's problem.

Comment: @JinghuiNiu you should `JSON.stringify()` the object you're passing to `$.getJSON()` first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for webKnjaZ's comment, using `JSON.stringify` is the correct solution to such a glitch.